# kafka on EC2 instance: not able to ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I am using kafka on ec2 INSTANCE. Kafka cluster has single node, three broker and some topics with replication factor of 3. Zookeeper is running in standalone mode.
After few hours I am not able to ssh to my machine. I have to reboot it every time.

Not able to figure out the issue. Any help appreciated!!
EDIT:
using ssh -v:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-[ip].compute-1.amazonaws.com [ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address [ip] port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ec2-[ip].compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ssh -v .....` command when it is working and when it is not working?

Comment: @hellpv: made the edits in question plz see

Comment: Having this same problem, experienced the same problem on both amazon linux and ubuntu whilst running confluent platform, did you resolve this in the end?